# Vaadin LoginForm. Add component to the custom place in the page

Tags: java, authentication, layout, vaadin

In my Vaadin application i want that user have possibility to store his login/password in browser local storage. So i implemented LoginForm like it was described here https://vaadin.com/forum#!/thread/1977417 in comment by Sohan Machielse and this appoach works great (thx Sohan). So now I want to add in this static html, that returned from connector request, existing vaadin component (combobox with language selection). **So my question is how can i add vaadin component in static html?**
I tried to add to this static html "div" with location attribute and wrap all my layout to Custom layout and then add ComboBOx on the place, described in location attribute, but it's not work. Maybe i am doing something wrong cos' i do not know how exactly CustomLayout add components to the page. Maybe someone could explain me how Custom Layout works...

Answer (score 0):

Why You need to add Vaadin component exactly?
Vaadin components is AJAX, based on GWT. Embed it in pure html is not simply.
You can use simple html components "select" with language selector and return result in app.